# how to convert html to pdf with specific font or language using pdfmake

Tags: node.js, html, browserify, mean-stack, pdfmake

This is just a simple html file using pdfmake .
I click a button and then open a pdf file .
using :

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
```

it's ok , but now i want to see a specific language (ex:Bangla) in my pdfpage . how it is possible . please help or suggest me .

header part:

```
<head>
    <!--    <meta charset="utf-8" />-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>html to pdf</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
    <script src='pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js'></script>
    <script src='build/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
    <script src='build/vfs_fonts.js'></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
```

body part :

```
<body>

    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <div class="btn btn-success buttin_click_1" type="button">download</div>
        <div class="btn btn-danger button_click_2" type="button">open</div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Script :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var docDefinition = {
            content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake ami '
        };

        $('.buttin_click_1').click(function () {
            console.log('btn 1 clicked');
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
        });

        $('.button_click_2').click(function () {
            console.log('btn 2 clicked');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

1. **Import the Font** in pdfMake.
2. Afterwards update the vfs_fonts.js as described on [github](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/wiki/Custom-Fonts---client-side)
3. assign pdfMake.fonts in your javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        pdfMake.fonts = {
            'SolaimanLipi': {
                normal: 'SolaimanLipi-Regular.ttf',
                bold: 'SolaimanLipi-Medium.ttf'
            }
        };
        var docDefinition = {
            content: 'হ্যালো',
            defaultStyle:{
                font: 'SolaimanLipi'
            }
        };

        $('.buttin_click_1').click(function () {
            console.log('btn 1 clicked');
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
        });

        $('.button_click_2').click(function () {
            console.log('btn 2 clicked');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Bro I am really struggling with the dataTable to export PDF in Bangla. [link](http://live.datatables.net/sosegedi/1/edit)